# Find the Range and Domain of the following function

Tags: geometry, multivariable-calculus, 3d

The function is:

$f(x,y) = \frac{2}{\sqrt{3-x}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{4-y}}$

I have found the domain and the Range intuitively.

But how would I formally prove that my assumption of the Range and Domain is true?

Comment: The range is $\{f(x,y)\colon (x,y)\in D_f\}$ and you conjecture that it equals some set $A$. To prove it, one way to do it is to prove the inclusions $A\subseteq \{f(x,y)\colon (x,y)\in D_f\}$ and $\{f(x,y)\colon (x,y)\in D_f\}\subseteq A$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Informally, to find the domain, we simply examine sub-parts of the expression, looking for potentially illegal operations.  When we see a sub-part like $\sqrt{4-y}$, for example, we know that $4-y$ better be positive.  We find all such restrictions and then form their conjunction.

As far as [agnis](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/214939/agnis)'s WolframAlpha suggestion goes, it's hard to imagine a more "formal" computation than what the computer might do.  Your function

```
2*(3 - x)^(-1/2) + (4 - y)^(-1/2)
```

can be represented as a [graph theoretical tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_%28graph_theory%29):

[image]

We now [traverse the tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal).  Some nodes lead to restrictions; others do not.  For example, a `Plus` node is no difficulty, since we can always add any two real numbers.  We just record the visit and move on.  A `Power` node *can* lead to a problem.  Specifically, `Power[expression,exponent]` leads to the restriction `expression!=0`, whenever `exponent<0`.  Furthermore, `expression` must be non-negative if `exponent` is a rational number.  Thus, for example, the `Power` node on the right leads to the inequality $4-y>0$.  Finally, we take the intersection of all these parts.

Answer (score 2):

You can input Your function in [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=f%28x%2Cy%29%3D2%2FSqrt%5B3%E2%88%92x%5D%2B1%2FSqrt%5B4%E2%88%92y%5D)

From alternate form the domain and range is quite clear.

Comment: Is there any formal proof or method of showing this, rather than using Wolfram Alpha or any other graph plotting software

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the function is defined on $ \mathbb{R}^2 $; thus the domain has to contain elements of $ \mathbb{R}^2 $ such that the function gives a result in $ \mathbb{R} $.
For the range, you can observe that for every element in the domain of $f$ you have $f(x,y)>0$, then you notice that as $ x \rightarrow 3 $, $ y \rightarrow 4 $, $ f(x,y) $ takes arbitrary large values. Since the function is continuous on its domain, the range is thus $ (0,+\infty)$.